# How to host a asp.net core MVC app in IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I am familiar with .Net in general but new to ASP.Net Core. I just had my first "self-hosted" ASP.Net Core MVC app running (created using templet and runs under Kestrel by default) . What I would like to do now it to host it in-process with IIS. But what I am struggling with is that I couldn't seem to find a clear and detailed instruction/document about what I need to do to get it to work. I have tried various configuration changes on my own but nothing works so far. I am running .Net Core 3.1 and using VS.Net 2019 on my Windows 10 environment. If someone could point me to the right direction it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of saying "nothing works", pick up a tutorial like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio and say at which step you stuck. Only that makes a question answerable. Make sure you start again from a clean environment, because your previous attempts can leave a corrupt system.

Comment: You can refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/simple-way-to-host-your-asp-net-core-in-iis/. It should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you want to host the asp.net core application on the IIS. You should make sure you have installed the right hosting bundle.

Notice: No matter you use in-process or out-of-process, you all need install the IIS hosting bundle.

More details about how to install it, you could refer to this [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

After install the link, you could check your IIS module to make sure you have installed the right asp.net core module.

[image]

Then you could use VS to publish the application to right folder and create the IIS web site  as below:

[image]

[image]

Create IIS website:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brando! Just did everything you suggested: installed the IIS hosting bundle; published my MVC project to a folder and then, created an IIS website with it's physical path set to the published folder. When I test it using url http://localhost:5008/home/CallApi, however, I am getting a 500 error that says "This page isn’t working. localhost is currently unable to handle this request.". Note here 5008 is my port and I am using http for my testing, not https. When I run the MVC from within VS (selfhost, not through IIS, on a different port), it still works fine. What am I doing wrong here?